# Solve the given initial-value problem.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

y'' + y' + 5y = 0,    y(0) = y'(0) = 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solve this by assuming $y$ is of the form $y=C e^{k x}$. Plugging in we get 
$$ y'' + y' + 5y = (k^2 y) + (k y) + 5y = (k^2 + k + 5)y = 0. $$
This is solved when $k^2+k+5 = 0$, so plugging in the quadratic equation we have this is solved when $k=\frac{-1\pm i\sqrt{19}}{2}$. Subbing back into $y$ we get $y = C_1 e^{\frac{-1+ i\sqrt{19}}{2}x} + C_2 e^{\frac{-1- i\sqrt{19}}{2}x}$, two terms since there are two possible $k$. This can be further simplified into $y=e^{-x/2}(c_1 \cos{\frac{\sqrt{19}}{2}x} + c_2 \sin{\frac{\sqrt{19}}{2} x})$. Since $y(0)=0$, set $x$ to $0$ to find $y(0)=e^{-0/2}(c_1 \cos{\frac{\sqrt{19}}{2}\,0} + c_2 \sin{\frac{\sqrt{19}}{2}\,0}) = c_1$, and so $c_1 = 0$. Taking the derivative at zero gives us $y'(0)=c_2$, so $c_2=0$.

Unfortunately this means $y(x) = e^{-x/2}(0+0)=0$, so $y(x)=0$.

Comment: I'm think I might have been confusing concepts, but is this right at all? $y''=5y-y'$. Integrating yields $y'=\frac{5}{2}y^2-y+c_1$. Since $y'(0)=0$, Then $0=c_1$. Then take another integral. You get: $y=\frac{5}{6}y^3-\frac{1}{2}y^2+c_2.$ Since $y(0)=0$, then $c_2=0$. You then have the equation $y=\frac{5}{6}y^3-\frac{1}{2}y^2$.

Comment: Kind of – the integral of $5y$ _with respect to $y$_ is $\frac{5}{2}y^2$, but the integral _with respect to $x$_ is not. This particular problem is not really solvable using that integration method.

Comment: ok, thanks. I kinda see where I messed up.